# Group by not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Needs help with my SQL query

```
Query : 

Select customer_id,
       if (call_details ='International' , 'International Calls', 'National Calls'),
       sum(minutes) 
from call_minutes 
where date between '$from' and '$to' 
group by call_details
```

My Result is displaying as below

[image]

Please let me know why National Calls is not getting grouped. I wanted to find the sum of national calls and international calls

Comment: You can't have customer_id in the select list and expect it to group properly. Which customer_id should it display for 'National Calls'?

Comment: You're grouping by call_details, so it is impossible to tell since you have not shown what is actually in that field.

Comment: customer id is the same for all calls and it is not the primary key. I just wanted to display the customer_id. Let me try without customer key

Comment: call_details contains International, NSW,SA,QLD,WA. If it is international I want to display 'International calls' else 'National Calls'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery for this, because MySQL allows you to use column aliases in the `group by` (not all databases do).  So:

```
Select customer_id,
       (case when call_details = 'International'
             then 'International Calls'
             else 'National Calls'
        end) as call_group,
       sum(minutes) 
from call_minutes 
where date between '$from' and '$to' 
group by customer_id, call_group;
```

Note:  this assumes that you want separate rows for each customer.  If not, remove `customer_id` from both the `select` and the `group by`:

```
Select (case when call_details = 'International'
             then 'International Calls'
             else 'National Calls'
        end) as call_group,
       sum(minutes) 
from call_minutes 
where date between '$from' and '$to' 
group by call_group;
```

If you want a list of customer ids in each group, you can always add `group_concat(customer_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

use below SQL:

```
select customer_id,
       call_details,
       sum(minutes) as minutes
from(
Select customer_id,
       if (call_details ='International' , 'International Calls', 'National Calls') as call_details,
       minutes
from call_minutes 
where date between '$from' and '$to') x 
group by customer_id,call_details
```

Comment: Thanks KKK. I got more doubt..Simple one ;). Why I am getting the error unknown column minutes  in the filed list when trying to run this query

Comment: unknown column mean the column does not exists in table, re-check the name of column

Comment: Stupid question. It was spelling mistake. Thanks KKK. You are a star. I got the answer. You found it

Comment: In information is useful you may mark question as answered